# Space Between Row inside DIV in Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap Grid System, everything is fine in Large Devices but in Small Devices div has not space between.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-6">
<span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>&nbsp;Month<label style="color: red"></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-6">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMonth" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-6">
 <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>&nbsp;Year<label style="color: red"></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-6">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtYear" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

There is no Space between these rows in Mobile Devices,How to solve it? In large devices it is fine because it is in same row and it has spacing between them. 
I can solve it by doing Padding or Margin in each div, but is it right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try mediaQueries

Example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .elemToBeChanged {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}
```

With that code You will make sure that specific styling in applied only on screens with max-screen width of 600 px :) You can set a margin to move the elements from each other inside the mediaQuery.

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

You could try using one of the [bootstrap utility classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/) (.pt & .pb) to introduce some top and bottom padding in the column divs.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-6 pt-2 pb-2">
<span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>&nbsp;Month<label style="color: red"></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-6 pt-2 pb-2">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMonth" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-6 pt-2 pb-2">
 <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>&nbsp;Year<label style="color: red"></label>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-6 pt-2 pb-2">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtYear" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
 </div>
</div>
```